# What is the best way to find available hours from working hours

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to develop my new project for appointments application.

I'm trying to let the user choose start hour and end hour for his business and then let his customers schedule an appointment.

For example:

```
{
  openHour: '08:00',
  closeHour: '18:00',
  someServiceDuration: 900000 // 15 minutes in ms
}
```

I want to display to the users all the working hours but only the busy hours will be disabled.
For example:

```
<select name="available-hours">
  {workingHoursFromDB.map(({hour, isAvailable}) => {
     <option 
       value={hour} 
       disabled={isAvailable}>
       {hour}
     </option>
   })}
</select>
```

So, Assuming the working hours is between 08:00 to 18:00 and the service duration is 15 min,

If someone schedules an appointment between 08:10 to 08:25,

The options that will be **NOT** disabled in the select element will be:
08:25, 08:30, 08:35 and so on...

The hours: 08:00, 08:05 **will be disabled** because the service duration is 15 minutes and there is not enough time for a new appointment.

I'm working with React and MongoDB.
Please show me the simplest way to make this done.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid computing available time slots based on scheduled dates.

Your option list can very easily exceed few hundred elements.

Just imagine `8:00, 8:01, 8:02, ..., 17:45`

With the small help of momentjs library it can be implemented following way.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const duration = 15;
const format = "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm";

const getRange = (timePart) => {
   const [hour, minute] = timePart.split(':').map(pr => Number(pr));
  const from = moment().startOf('day').set({
    hour,
    minute
  });
  const to = from.clone().add(duration, 'minutes');
  
  return [from.format(format), to.format(format)];
}

const getWorkingHours = (() => {
  const today = moment().startOf('day');
    
  const from = today.set({hour: 8})
  const to = today.clone().set({hour: 18})
    
  const result = [from.format(format), to.format(format)];
  
  return () => result
})()

const getMockReservedDate = () => {
  const today = moment().startOf('day');
  
  const from = today.set({hour: 8, minute: 10});
  const to = today.clone().add(duration, 'minutes');

  const result = [from.format(format), to.format(format)];
  
  return result;
}

const App = () => {
  const [reserved, setReserved] = useState([
    getMockReservedDate()
  ]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const [hasError, setError] = useState('');
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
  
  
  useEffect(() => {
    moment();
    
  }, [])
  
  const isBetweenWorkingHours = ([from, to]) => {
    const [start, end] = getWorkingHours()
    
    const fromMomentObj = moment(from);
    const toMomentObj = moment(to);
 
    if((!fromMomentObj.isBetween(start, end) 
      && !fromMomentObj.isSame(start))
    ||
      (!toMomentObj.isBetween(start, end)
      && !toMomentObj.isSame(end))
    ) {
      return false;
    }
    
    return true;
  }
  
  const onChange = ({target: {value}}) => {
    setValue(value);
    const range = getRange(value);
    
    if(!isBetweenWorkingHours(range)) {
      setError('Outside working hours');
      setDisabled(true);
      return;
    }
    
    for(const [from, to] of reserved) {
      const fromMomentObj = moment(range[0]);
      const toMomentObj = moment(range[1]);
    
      if(fromMomentObj.isBetween(from, to) ||
        toMomentObj.isBetween(from, to) ||
        fromMomentObj.isSame(from) ||
        toMomentObj.isSame(to)
      ) {
        setError(`Dates overlap ${from} -> ${to}`);
        setDisabled(true);
        
        return;
      }
    }
    
    setError('');
    setDisabled(false);
  }
  
  const onClick = () => {
    const range = getRange(value);
    
    setReserved(reserved => [...reserved, range])
    setValue('');
  }
  
  return <div>
      <div>Reserved {JSON.stringify(reserved)}</div>
    <div>
      <input min="08:00" max="18:00" required type="time" value={value} onChange={onChange}/>
      <div className={`message ${hasError ? 'error': ''}`}>{hasError}</div>
      <button disabled={disabled} onClick={onClick}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```css
.message {
  display: none;
}

.error {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```